# Android Win Death - app died, no saved state

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin, android-asynctask, xamarin.android

I have an Android app which launches an asynctask to synchronyze files with a remote FTP. The syncing process is done on background so that we can still open and read files. For a reason that I don't understand after a few hours of testing my app keeps crashing randomly with the messages following :

> 04-21 14:26:47.926 SM-T585 : Warning    5355    ActivityManager Force removing ActivityRecord{easyDoc/md516a8905f8e96d5.MainActivity t1431}: app died, no saved state
>   04-21 14:26:47.926 SM-T585 : Info   5355    WindowState WIN DEATH: Window{47e1c65 u0 d0 easyDoc/md516a8905f8e96d5.MainActivity}
>   04-21 14:26:47.926 SM-T585 : Debug  5355    ActivityManager removeProcessNameLocked mProcessNames.remove pid=20496 ,hash=156239617 ,name=easyDoc
>   04-21 14:26:47.926 SM-T585 : Info   5355    ActivityManager Process easyDoc.easyDoc (pid 20496)(adj 0) has died(105,633)
>   04-21 14:26:47.926 SM-T585 : Debug  5355    ActivityManager isAutoRunBlockedApp:: easyDoc.easyDoc, Auto Run ON

What can I do to debug this and prevent my app to be killed by the activity manager ?

Comment: So when your app crash is it always in the background?

Comment: My app is open and I can use it but the process syncing files is running in background until everything crashes. If I open the multi-task I can still see it there though...

Comment: I see there, OS should not destroy your app. But perhaps this could be just something related to `AsyncTask` since they are not recommended to be used for long tasks. Try a sticky `Service` instead as @mVck has suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there's nothing you can do to prevent the OS from killing your app, and you should not try to do that. Do not fight the system.

For such a big job (synchronizing files with an FTP server) you should try to use a `Service` instead of an AsyncTask. It's pretty simple to implement, check out the documentation of `IntentService` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Comment: You are right there is no way to stop OS from killing the app. However for tasks that take a long time to complete a good idea would to be to add a notification and update progress in it continuously so your `Service` is interacting with the main thread. Which *should keep* it from getting killed.

Comment: I am sending toasts during the whole process (every 5% done) but it is not enough... I'll give a try with the service to see if it makes a change and will keep you posted.

Comment: IntentService solved my problem, AsyncTask is not to be used with long/demanding processes.

Comment: But if we can find the reason for been killed, we may avoid that?